# How can I only print a value if it is greater than zero?

Tags: python

I am creating a coin return calculator. I have all the code wrote but I can't figure out how to only display the coins that are needed instead of getting the coins I don't need.

```
Enter change amount to convert: 3
0 quarter(s)
0 dime(s)
0 nickle(s)
3 penny(ies)
Want to calculate another amount? (y/n):
```

I want to not display the quarters, dimes or nickles.

```py
while True:
    change = input("Enter change amount to convert: ")
    if str(change).isnumeric():
        change = int(change)
        if change < 100:
            quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies = coinCalc(change)
            print(quarters, "quarter(s)")
            print(dimes, "dime(s)")
            print(nickels, "nickle(s)")
            print(pennies, "penny(ies)")
            print("Want to calculate another amount? (y/n): ")
            answer = input()
            if answer == "n":
                print("Bye!")
                break
        else:
            print("Error! Invalid integer entered please try again.")
    else:
        print("Error! Invalid integer entered please try again.")
```

Comment: One option is jut to check whether the number is above 0 before the print, like `if quarters >0: print(quarters); if dimes >0...`

Comment: What does this have to do with pytest?

Comment: Why did you not use the same techniques you already used for only calculating the change if the amount is less than 100?

Answer (score 1):

You could add an if-statement to check whether the coin's value is zero. If so, then don't print it.

```py
if quarters != 0:
    print(quarters, "quarter(s)")
if dimes != 0:
    print(dimes, "dime(s)")
if nickels != 0:
    print(nickels, "nickle(s)")
if pennies != 0:
    print(pennies, "penny(ies)")
print("Want to calculate another amount? (y/n): ")
```